# Installing MatplotLib in mac osx lion

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, osx-lion

I was trying to install matplotlib in Mac OSX Lion. Tried to used the binary that is in the sourcefourge site, but I got this error: "matplotlib requires System Python 2.7 to install".

I went to the Terminal and typed python --version and its check the requirements.

After this I tried to used the pip, and while doing so é got the following error:

"src/_image.cpp:908: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct png_info_def’"

Can you give me clues in how to install it?

Many thanks.

EDIT: I found a way, without having to install a new version of python:

http://the.taoofmac.com/space/blog/2011/07/24/2222

Comment: Doesn't work with Python 2.7 on Lion 10.7.3. The build 'crashes' with hundreds of errors.

Comment: i found the answer here: http://superuser.com/a/267204/46361

Comment: Had good luck with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363557/matplotlib-install-failure-on-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion installing freetype and libpng via Homebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with an "official" python distribution, apple might have tweaked the supplied one. You can find the 2.7 here: http://www.python.org/download/ 
You might have to re-install numpy as well afterwords: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/

I would suggest to install scipy as well 
Let me know if it works ;)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. Well I was able to install it, but got a small problem. the python.org version of 2.7 is 64 bits, and we only have a 32 bits version of matplotlib. Do you have any idea how to change python to work on 32 bits mode?

Comment: what about this?
http://voidptr.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/compiling-matplotlib-1-0-1-on-64-bit-mac-os-x-leopard-for-python-2-7/

Comment: Already tried it. It gives me the error that I posted about the libpng. I already tried to install the libpng, but the result was the same.

Comment: I just managed to get it to work. Now I have a problem with the show() method, but it does not matter. I use the save fig instead. Thank you very much.

Comment: So what did you ended up doing? to make it work with the 32 bit matplotlib?

Comment: So, this ended up fixing my problem :D

Answer (score 9):

This is because of a change in the API for libpng v1.5 (which is included with Mac OSX Lion). The changes has already been pushed upstream, so you will need to compile from the upstream repository until the next release.

You can follow the instructions on http://jholewinski.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/installing-matplotlib-on-os-x-10-7-with-homebrew/

Comment: This is correct. The only qualification is that while I did have pkg-config installed with Homebrew, I did not need gfortran or the Homebrew python. To use easy_install, we need to wait for the next version of matplotlib (v1.0.2 likely)

Comment: ``pip install -e git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=Package`` seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 5):

I followed this [page's instructions](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/). I got stuck at

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib#egg=matplotlib-dev
```

Then I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Checked my installation by typing in terminal:

```
python
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__version__
print matplotlib.__file__
```

I got version 0.10.0 dev (as of this writing) and path /usr/local/Cellar/...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [macports](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=matplotlib), it should take care of dependencies and would be indepedent of the system python version.

**EDIT**: Just a few clarifications, taking into account comments to this answer.

Why use macports (or another installer)? Because they take care of dependencies, provide functionality to uninstall and switch between versions (I've used the latter successfully for gcc and python). And because the default installation location is not the system executable location. Overriding the system python can break applications that rely on it (this is certainly true in many Linux distributions, maybe less so on mac OS X).

When is it particularly useful? When you want to install on top of a version of python that is different to system python, and when you have non-python extensions (C, C++, Fortran...).

What's the down side? As @Trond has mentioned in the comments, it is good if you're OK with default compilations of packages. You don't have a handle over configuration or compiler flags as you would if you built from source.

A good alternative to macports is [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), which seems to give you more control (build from source). I am not sure it is completely ready for mac OS X Lion yet.

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment? If there's something wrong with the answer I'll gladly fix it or remove it all together.

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but I don't really consider this an answer either). Normally in OS X, you're able to install python packages using easy_install. OS X leaves /Library/Python/$VERSION/site-packages to be used for user installation. Using macports would require having an additional complete python install on the system, which isn't all that awesome.

Comment: I've found it quite useful using macports or fink to install 3rd party python libraries which may require a version of python that isn't the same as system python. Changing system python invariably leads to trouble. With macports you can have self-contained installations and select which version of python you want to use. I only recommended this because I have tried installing matplotlib itself from the dmg, which required upgrading system python, and lead to all kinds of trouble. The macoprts solution works fine for me. I can use easy_install/pip to install on top macport-installed python

Comment: @juanchopanza: +1 from me, but for your comment regarding system python--i.e., why it's a bad idea to use it in your dev environment. FWIW, i am not a fan of MacPorts though. Let me suggest that you put that comment in your answer--it makes your answer better (more persuasive)--it's the implicit justification for your answer anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Macports is good if you are satisified with the default compilation of Python, but Macports will not be able to satisfy all your dependencies if you want support for Fortran, zlib, NetCDF etc. At that point it makes sense to compile from source.

Comment: @Trond very good point. I'll expand my answer later and add a comment about this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just install the Python 2.6 version of Matplotlib, assuming that Python2.6 is included with Lion (py2.5 & 2.6 are included with Mac OS 10.6 "Snow Leopard" - try typing ***python2.6*** to find out if that version is installed.).

On MacPorts you do this via something like:

```
sudo port install py26-matplotlib
```

where py26-... (or py25-..., py27-... etc.) indicates which python version it is meant for. (check the Pallet/ports list to get the correct package name, in case I guessed wrong)