# Matplotlib install failure on Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: matplotlib

I tried to install matplotlib on my MacBook Air, but it always gives me this error message:

```
 Processing matplotlib-1.1.1_notests.tar.gz
 Running matplotlib-1.1.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-3jFpXK/matplotlib-1.1.1/egg-dist-tmp-jC7QY3
    basedirlist is: []
    ============================================================================
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: 1.1.1
                    python: 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33)  [GCC 4.2.1
                            Compatible Apple Clang 4.0
                            (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]
                  platform: darwin

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                     numpy: 1.6.1
                 freetype2: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
                            * WARNING: Could not find 'freetype2' headers in any
                            * of '.', './freetype2'.

    OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                    libpng: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
                            * Could not find 'libpng' headers in any of '.'
                   Tkinter: Tkinter: version not identified, Tk: 8.5, Tcl: 8.5
                      Gtk+: no
                            * Building for Gtk+ requires pygtk; you must be able
                            * to "import gtk" in your build/install environment
           Mac OS X native: yes
                        Qt: no
                       Qt4: no
                    PySide: no
                     Cairo: no

    OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
                  datetime: present, version unknown
                  dateutil: 1.5
                      pytz: matplotlib will provide
    adding pytz

    OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: 1.14
               ghostscript: 9.05
                     latex: 3.1415926

    [Edit setup.cfg to suppress the above messages]




  pymods ['pylab']
    packages ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor', 'matplotlib.projections', 'matplotlib.testing', 'matplotlib.testing.jpl_units', 'matplotlib.tests', 'mpl_toolkits', 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1', 'mpl_toolkits.axisartist', 'matplotlib.sphinxext', 'matplotlib.tri', 'matplotlib.delaunay', 'pytz']
    warning: no files found matching 'KNOWN_BUGS'
    warning: no files found matching 'INTERACTIVE'
    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching '__init__.py'
    warning: no files found matching 'examples/data/*'
    warning: no files found matching 'lib/mpl_toolkits'
    warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE*' under directory 'license'
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
    src/ft2font.h:16:10: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found

**#include <ft2build.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1**
```

I tried to install freetype and libpng using homebrew but it doesn't work. How can I get ft2build.h?

Comment: I had the same problem. My problem was that the Github servers were down when I tried to install Homebrew packages so I dot not manage to download all packages. The right answers are provided, I think, below so probably you will now succeed if you try.

Comment: For the record, I had a different error: `#error Tk 8.5 must be compiled with tcl.h from Tcl 8.5` with `matplotlib 1.5` in a `virtualenv` on Python 2.7.10+ built from source. It was looking at the system Tk. With MacPorts, `port install tk` solved the problem (`tcl` was already installed via MacPorts).

Answer (score 36):

The following worked for matplotlib installation after installing python according to instructions from [thegreenroom](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/#lion).  Those instructions didn't work for me after I installed Python.  I followed the instructions from [Scipy.org](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X#head-9ec15aabd402675e5139a8c9c727e6a23513d56a%20Scipy.org) to install numpy and scipy.  Then I did (adapted from above answer):

```
brew install freetype
brew install libpng
```

However I got the same error message whether I installed with `pip install matplotlib` or trying to install from source, doing

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

in the matplotlib directory I cloned via `git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git`.

The error persisted until I ran

```
brew link freetype
```

Then from the cloned matplotlib directory I ran

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

And the installation succeeded.

Comment: For the record, Apple does not distribute libpng / freetype from OSX 10.8 on. This is the error I see returned: `$ brew install libpng
Error: No available formula for libpng
Apple distributed libpng with OS X until 10.8. It is also distributed
as part of XQuartz. You can find the XQuartz installer here:
  http://xquartz.macosforge.org`

Comment: @msunbot, Thanks! Good to know, I did this on 10.7 before I upgraded. Did you get matplotlib installed after getting XQuartz?

Comment: At the build step, I see the following error: `src/ft2font.cpp:854: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ but no definition available
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Answer (score 26):

This may help folks looking for a non-homebrew solution.

My goal: use `pip install` to build matplotlib for a non-system python 2.7.3 build.

Using latest X-Code and X-Code command line tools as of Feb 2013, no matter what gymnastics I tried, I always received C++ ostream related template errors when compiling ft2build with gcc.

I was able to get a pip install to work with the following env vars:

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/X11/lib"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/X11/include/freetype2"
```

I simply forced clang and added my xquartz paths. No extra pkg-config or libpng builds, no sudo-ed symlinks.

Comment: Worked for me as well when all other options failed.

Comment: Worked on OS X 10.9.1 "Mavericks". You have my +1. Many thanks!

Comment: This dirty quickfix worked for me as well! I read it, for some reason discarded it, and then came back after two hours.

Answer (score 8):

I think the other answers are on the right track, but I encountered this same problem and can attest that:

```
brew install pkg-config
brew install freetype
pip install matplotlib
```

would yield the same result.  Typically on an Ubuntu box my next response would have been

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype-dev
```

or some variation of that to install the header.  However, I could find no such homebrew package.  Furthermore, I was able to locate the header file in question in a pretty normal location on my system:

```
zoidberg:~ matt$ locate ft2build.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/X11/include/ft2build.h
/usr/X11/include/ft2build.h
```

So I suspect there's either a problem with my system paths or with the homebrew packaged matplotlib.  Since I'm lazy, I just tried installing the matplotlib package head from github:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib-dev
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: The pkg-config was the missing piece for me.  Once I brew installed it everything started working.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the brew + pip recipe I used from a cold start.  If you already have python and gfortran and such, jump in at the point where you need.  The crucial steps appear to be `brew install freetype` and `brew install libpng` prior to doing `pip install matplotlib`

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
$ brew doctor
$ brew install python
$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
$ easy_install pip
$ brew install gfortran
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install scipy
$ brew install pkg-config
$ brew install freetype
$ brew install libpng
$ pip install matplotlib
$ python
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import matplotlib
```

Answer (score 2):

Note the 'no pkg-config' notices. You should have `pkg-config` on your search path, and it presumably needs to be the homebrew version so that it knows where the homebrew versions of the libraries are.

Answer (score 2):

You need freetype:

```
brew install freetype
```

See the following:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general/31394

Answer (score 1):

I also use mac air with OS X ver 10.8.2.

Using following commands can get rid of this failure:
brew install freetype
brew install libpng
pip install matplotlib

That's all. There may be some warning in the installing process, but that does not affect.

Use following python code to test:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

which is referred from the url: http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have found installing these pacakges via homebrew to be the most reliable method

```
 # if you haven't installed python via brew already:
 brew install python

 # sets up python as default python instead of system python
 brew link python

 # Add more brew formulae so we can install our py libs with brew
 brew tap samueljohn/python
 brew tap homebrew/science

 # install numpy,scipy,matplotlib and dependencies ( gfortran, etc.. )
 brew install numpy
 brew install scipy
 brew insatll matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using MacOs 10.8 too, and I encountered the same problem regarding not finding ft2build.h header  when I tried to install matplotlib, what I l did to resolve the reported issue is :

1) replacing "ft2build.h" in the following call within the file "setupext.py" :

```
                                 return self._check_for_pkg_config('freetype2', 
                                 'ft2build.h',
                                  min_version='2.4', 
                                  version=version)
```

by the complete path to the ft2build.h header, in my case :

```
                                return self._check_for_pkg_config('freetype2', 
                               '/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.2/include/freetype2/ft2build.h',
                                min_version='2.4', 
                                version=version)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, but have not tested, that the problem is solved in an upstream commit of matplotlib. Here is my reasons why:

Discussion:

https://github.com/vbraun/sage/commit/5d17ca989eb58559af8f43b43e368c378c1bf6bb

Fix:

https://github.com/vbraun/sage/blob/5d17ca989eb58559af8f43b43e368c378c1bf6bb/build/pkgs/matplotlib/patches/pkg-config.patch

I fixed the problem with Cyris's answer thought.

Answer (score -1):

I also had a similar issue, and fixed it in a reasonably straightforward way using homebrew.

You don't have to link the `freetype` libraries for this reason. The main problem is, after you install `freetype` using homebrew, you are told to add

```
-I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include
```

to your CPPFLAGS. However, this alone is not sufficient, and you also have to add the the `freetype2` subfolder as well.

So in order to install matplotlib, do this:

```
brew install freetype
brew install libpng
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include -I/usr/local/opt/libpng/include -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2" pip install matplotlib
```