# Unable to install matplotlib on OSX 10.8.4 with VirtualEnv

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-mountain-lion, virtualenv

I tried every single link that is available on the web but still I am getting following error:

```
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.4.x]
                python: yes [2.7.5 (default, Jul 28 2013, 07:27:04)  [GCC
                        4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)]]
              platform: yes [darwin]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.7.1]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [pkg-config information for 'freetype2' could
                        not be found.]
                   png: yes [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                        be found. Using unknown version.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: yes [darwin]
                qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [version 81008]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairo not found]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: no
                 latex: no
               pdftops: no
============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype
```

Here are the things that I tried:

I successfully install `numpy` and `scipy` in my native python environment. Since I was not able to install `matplotlib` I decided to switch to `virtualenv`.

Here are the links:

- Instructions from [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#install-from-git)
- Blog post from [this is the green room](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800488/installing-matplotlib-in-mac-osx-lion)

Every single option ended up with the above issue. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If haven't yet install [brew](http://brew.sh) with:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
```

and then do:

```
brew install freetype
brew install libpng
```

The last line is probably not needed but just to be sure. Then try again with `pip`.

EDIT:
I also suggest you try the [conda](http://continuum.io/blog/anaconda-python-3) installer.

Comment: sorry forgot to put it in my question i tried installing freetype bit didn't install libpng i ll try that part.

Comment: well it seems that freetype is not being found, you can try looking at the instructions given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10843478/1330293)